# How do interface a LIDAR device with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, usb, sensors, simulink, lidar

I have a Hokuyo USB LADAR/LIDAR. I have problem with interfacing or connecting it to MATLAB/Simulink, such that I can do all the processing in those software packages.

I have already asked Hokuyo. They only provide C++ program interface ([sample programming guide and libraries](http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/urg_programs_en/)). How do I interface this to MATLAB/Simulink?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [mex files](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html). You can embed c++ code in matlab as well as simulink.

Comment: mex functions (matlab) and sfunctions (simulink) are not the same. It's a bit more than copying, but manageable with basic c/c++ programming skills. Check the documentation for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

The web page you pointed to has a C API in `urg_ctrl.h`.  I assume this comes with a DLL that implements the API?  If so, you can use Matlab's interface for [calling external libraries](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f43202.html). The basic procedure is to have Matlab parse the header file using LOADLIBRARY, then view the available functions using LIBFUNCTIONS and call functions using CALLLIB.

I imagine, though I've never done it, that you can write .m functions to access the device that you can then wrap in Simulink blocks.

Comment: thanks, u seems know a lot about it,, can u give me the sample demos or model??

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Matlab anymore (too expensive).  But the documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f43202.html) is pretty clear.  Just follow the steps of using LOADLIBRARY, LIBFUNCTIONS, and CALLLIB.